# mysql (MariaDB) で localhost、127.0.0.1、::1 それぞれに接続するには？

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

mysql( 10.1.30-MariaDB)をインストールすると、

```
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+----------+
| host      | user | password                                  | ssl_type |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+----------+
| localhost | root |                                           |          |
| 127.0.0.1 | root |                                           |          |
| ::1       | root | 　　　　　                                |          |
| localhost |      |                                           |          |
| localhost | pma  |                                           |          |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+----------+
```

という五つのユーザーがあります。

ここで二つ質問があります。

１．mysql -u root -p **と入力するとこの三つのうち恐らくhostがlocalhostのものに接続しますが、127.0.0.1や::1に接続する際は、 mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p **やmysql -h ::1 -u root -p ****とすると接続できますか。
それぞれ三つのアカウントに接続したうえでselect current_user()をしても

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

としか返ってこなかったので恐らくどうやってもlocalhostにしか接続できていないと思うのです。てっきりroot@127.0.0.1、root@::1になるのかと思ったのですが、なぜならないのでしょうか。
というかどうするとこれらのhostに接続できますか。

２．::1は、ipv6を利用している方のためのものだとは思うのですが、そのipv6を利用している場合は、hostがlocalhost、127.0.0.1では接続できないということなのでしょうか。

https://teratail.com/questions/115682

Answer (score 3):

`-hlocalhost` 指定時はUNIXソケット接続で、mysqld のユーザーも `username@localhost` になります。

`-h127.0.0.1`, `-h::1` 指定時はTCP/IP接続になりますが、この時どのユーザーになるかは、mysqld の `skip-name-resolve` の設定に依存します。

`skip-name-resolve=false` の時(デフォルト)は、IPアドレスからホスト名を得ようとするので、`127.0.0.1`, `::1` はどちらも `username@localhost` ユーザーになります。

`skip-name-resolve=true` の時は、IPアドレスをそのまま使用するので、`username@127.0.0.1`, `username@::1` ユーザーになります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
my.iniのmysqldブロックにslip-name-resolve=trueを追加して接続を試みてみたところ、
C:\WINDOWS\system32>mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
Enter password: **********
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

C:\WINDOWS\system32>mysql -u root -h localhost -p
Enter password: **********
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '::1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
となりました。
以下それとなく関連してそうな頁を閲覧しましたが、解決には至りませんでした。
https://blog.csdn.net/vbaspdelphi/article/details/54954513
https://yoku0825.blogspot.jp/2015/02/mysql-575-on-windowsskip-name.html
どうすれば解決できるでしょうか。